# How to Compare PropertyInfo types

Tags: c#, .net

I compare two `PropertyInfo` types using

```
if(p1.GetType() == p2.GetType())
{
     // same type
}
```

My problem is that this yields true when `p1` is of type `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection` and `p2` is `System.String`.

What is the correct way to do the comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoking `p1.GetType()` gets you `typeof(PropertyInfo)`, because this is of course the type of the object.

If you want to know, what type the property is you can use `p1.PropertyType`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/3893z9ey(v=vs.110).aspx

So your code will be:

```
if(p1.PropertyType == p2.PropertyType) 
{
    // some code
}
```

Comment: Also, although not good, but you can use p1.GetType().Name for comparison.

Comment: Also, if you want to adhere by object-oriented principles, you shouldn't check for exact type matching. Look into the `IsAssignableFrom` method of the `Type` class.